# @RefreshScope not working - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am following the approach described here: https://github.com/jeroenbellen/blog-manage-and-reload-spring-properties, the only difference is that in my case, the properties are being used in multiple classes so I have put them all in one utility class `CloudConfig` and I refer to its variables using the getters. This is what the class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class CloudConfig {

    static volatile int count; // 20 sec

    @Value("${config.count}")
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

and I use the variable `count` in other classes like `CloudConfig.getCount()`. I am able to load the properties on bootup just fine but I am not able to dynamically update them on the fly. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? If instead of making this config class, I do exactly what the tutorial describes everything works fine but I am having trouble adapting it to my usecase. Can anybody tell what I am missing?

Comment: If the other classes are singletons and only load those values at startup, they will not get fresh values after a refresh.

Comment: Yeah but those in CloudConfig will, and I will use getters (CloudConfig.getCount()) in other classes so they'll get the right values also. Correct?

Comment: If you only use the getters to set the values once no they won't, also they shouldn't be static but regular methods else proxy creation will fail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) instead. 
e.g.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")
public class CloudConfig {

    private Integer count;

    public Integer count() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

The [reference doc from spring cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) states:

> @RefreshScope works (technically) on an @Configuration class, but it
>   might lead to surprising behaviour: e.g. it does not mean that all the
>   @Beans defined in that class are themselves @RefreshScope.
>   Specifically, anything that depends on those beans cannot rely on them
>   being updated when a refresh is initiated, unless it is itself in
>   @RefreshScope (in which it will be rebuilt on a refresh and its
>   dependencies re-injected, at which point they will be re-initialized
>   from the refreshed @Configuration).

Comment: but how do we refer to these in the other beans?

Comment: Autowire the ConfigurationProperties into your service. It is described in the end of this paragraph https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: Spring docs says following about ConfigurationProperties:-
Annotation for externalized configuration. Add this to a class definition or a Bean method in a Configuration class if you want to bind and validate some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).

May i know how it's related to RefershScope ??

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else facing this issue, please make sure the followings:

1. Your controller is annotated with `@RefreshScope`
2. Spring boot actuator is added into your dependency, as it is the module which actually provides these endpoints:

   > org.springframework.boot
   >           spring-boot-starter-actuator
3. Refresh endpoint has been updated to:

   http://{ip_address}:{port}/actuator/refresh
4. Refresh endpoint isn't enabled by default. You have to enable it explicitly in the ***bootstrap.properties*** file by adding the following line:

   `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

I have enabled all the endpoints, while you can just enable the specific endpoints as well.

Comment: Your answer is wrong on multiple counts. There is no reason to annotate the controller with `@RefreshScope`, and actuator is only required if manual refresh is  desired.

Comment: In previous version it was required, may be not required anymore in the latest version. Still it doesn't make any sense when answer is solving the problem.