# Spring config @RefreshScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

Can I use `@RefreshScope` (along with `@Value` on a property) only in Cloud config server or can I use without config server as well? I'm trying to use it without config server. I am trying to fetch `@Value` property by changing value in a .property file and trying to request again, will I get updated value? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should use it along with Config server otherwise you won't be able to read the update properties on fly. Follow [this article](https://github.com/jeroenbellen/blog-manage-and-reload-spring-properties) and have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137555/refreshscope-not-working-spring-boot) if you face any issue loading updated properties dynamically.

> In theory, you could refresh the application context, but I wouldn't
>   recommend this. Spring Cloud has provided an annotation to mark a bean
>   as refreshable. By adding spring actuator, we can refresh those beans
>   on the fly.